# textfield/textarea with 2 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ON IE

when I do

```
<textarea style="overflow :auto" rows="2" cols="10"/>
```

I see a scroll bar.  I don't know if I remove the overflow style (removes the scrollbar) that I will get the same thing as a Textfield?

So basically a textfield with 2 rows.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Set the *overflow* attribute to `hidden`. If you keep it as `auto` the scroll bars will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what the end of your question means, but if you remove `style="overflow :auto"` it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the closing `</textarea>` tag?

**EDIT**

By the way, the code worked fine for me with the closing tag?

However, another thing you can do is set the height in the css.

```
<textarea cols="10"/></textarea>
```

css

```
textarea{height:70px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/xw7G8/